# Azure key vault. How to set which web app uses what key vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-webapps

I have several versions of the same web app running on the same subscription service.

I have 2 logical environments. Dev and UAT. 
I have WebAppDev and WebAppUAT.

I have two key vaults KVDev and KVUAT.
How can I configure the correct web app to use the correct key vault?

What process assigns the web apps to key vaults?

Edit:
I had assumed that the key vault would act like the secrets do when developing.

This
[Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

seems to suggest that the key vault can be used as a configuration provider. However, the web app is not accessing the key vault values.

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity.

Comment: You can just grant permissions to WebAppDev  to access KVDev and grant permissions to WebAppUAT to access KVUAT. this can be done through the access policy blade of KEy Vault (azure portal) or you can use az cli, az powershell or ARM template to script it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get the Object ID from the identity blade of the web app.
2. Find your azure key vault and create a new access policy using the Object Id of web app.

   Alternatively use the following in the powershell cli.

> Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy –VaultName  -ObjectId "" -PermissionsToKeys backup,create,delete,get,import,list,restore -PermissionsToSecrets get,list,backup,restore,recover

3. Follow this tutorial and copy the context from the Program.cs in the sample code.

[Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 3):

Taking a different angle, the current questions and comments tackle the authentication to KeyVault.

However, it sounds like a more fundamental problem and that you need to vary your configuration per environment.

i.e. WebAppDev needs to be configured to use a KVDev URL and WebAppUAT needs to use KVUAT URL.

Assuming you are using App Service Plans; this documentation provides a mechanism to store environment specific configuration along with guidance on how to use it for your programming language of choice, you will need to refer to the Application Specific configuration section.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common

Configuring in the portal will get you so far, but over time you will likely wish to contain the configuration in a release management pipeline so you don't need to configure things by hand. Azure DevOps Pipeline is one such tool for this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fpipelines%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops

To get you started there is a specific deployment task which can aid in setting configuration for App Service Plans: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops

Over time I'd suggest rather than splitting configuration between a Release Pipeline and source control, instead having configuration which doesn't require deployment time modifications instead to stay source controlled in ARM templates, but that is an answer in it's own right so I won't confuse matters with too much detail.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for the answer. I will investigate the links provided and if it works I'll pay the bounty.

Comment: No worries, I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am reading your answer in detail and following the links. I know how to set the config already and my question is very specific about the key vault. I am also aware of the pipe line and its benefits. Unfortunately your answer doesn't address the issue of assigning an web app a key vault.

Comment: When you say "assigning" can you clarify, do you mean which keyvault is set for each app? Or do you mean how to authenticate an app for accessing a keyvault? Or do you mean how to use the keyvault in an app?

Comment: Right now, I have given the web apps access to the secrets and keys in their respective vaults, using the managed identities scenario. However they are not reading the secrets.

Comment: Ah ha ok, what have you tried so far in reading the secrets? And what programming language are you using?

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for the help. I believe I know how to answer this now myself. I can up vote your answer but it didn't answer my question directly.

Comment: No worries, thanks glad you have got to the bottom of it. Please do share you solution in the end to help the community.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access Azure key Vault by programming with SDK or REST API, then it would not be a problem. Because different key vaults have different DNS names. When you try to retrieve a secret or key in your code, you need to use its identify URL which contains its key vault DNS name. It will finally find the target key vault.

If you want to use key vault in web app with managed identity, you may refer to the tutorial: [Use Azure Key Vault with an Azure web app in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app)

In that tutorial, you will enable the identity of a web app. And then you can assign access policy to that identity. In this way, the web app will be able to access the key vault with managed identity.

Comment: Right now the web app can access the key vault without any further configuration. Does Azure automatically assign a key vault on a first come first served basis for web apps?

Comment: No it doesn't. You have to lookup entires in the the target URI for KV store which looks like - https://<YourKeyVaultName>.vault.azure.net